# Interfacing printer with arduino and computer using existing device driver

Tags: arduino, driver, device-driver, printers

I'm working on a project in which a arduino is serially interfaced with a printer.
The goal of the project is to have the microcontroller as a middle step in the communication flow computer-printer in order to add some extra features.
Computer --> Printer
Computer --> Arduino --> Printer
The printer has a very nice windows device driver. Is it a way to keep the printer's driver interfacing the computer with the arduino?
I mean, is it possible for the arduino to be "seen" as a printer, installing the printer's driver package and have all the functionality with a sort of arduino-bridge?

Comment: I don't know anything about the Arduino, but for it to do what you're asking there would either need to be a print driver for the Arduino, or the Arduino would need to emulate the printer model you're using and have the ability to pass print data on to the printer.

Comment: @Francesco Was just wondering if you found a solution for this problem? I saw that the Arduino Cookbook has a new chapter for setting  your arduino up as a USB Device but I did not read it yet.